# What is regular expression for first field containing alpha-numeric?

Tags: sed

I have data that starts out like this in a .csv file

`"684MF7","684MF7","RN"`

The first field "684MF7" should only contain numeric characters; no alpha characters should be present in the first field. I have other checks for the second field, which in this case is also "684MF7", which is a legitimate value for the second field.

I want to find any alpha in the first field, and print that line. I invoke this sed file

```
{
        /^".*[^0-9]*.*",/p
}
```

with `-n` and `-f` (for the file name).

What regular expression isolates the first field only? I am getting a match on everything, which isn't what I want. Is my problem because I am trying to match zero or more instead of 1 or more alpha characters?

Comment: Might be because it's greedy?  It takes as much as it can, so it goes from the first quote all the way to the last?

Comment: Thanks, good edit. @Lev Levitsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first field (any content) would be selected by:

```
/^"[^"]*"/
```

You want at least one of the characters in the field to be alpha (though it might be better regarded as 'non-digit'), in which case one of these should select what you're after:

```
/^"[^"]*[A-Za-z][^"]*"/
/^"[^"]*[^0-9"][^"]*"/
/^"[^"]*[[:alpha:]][^"]*"/
/^"[^"]*[^"[:digit:]][^"]*"/
```

Note that the negated classes must not match a double quote either (one reason for always testing answers — the first version of the script below listed both lines of input).

And converting one of those into a `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/^"[^"]*[^"[:digit:]][^"]*"/p' <<EOF
"684MF7","684MF7","RN"
"684007","684MF7","RN"
EOF
```

Another way of looking at the problem is "print any line where the first field is not all digits (with at least one digit present)".  That is:

```
sed -n '/^"[[:digit:]]\{1,\}"/!p' <<EOF
"684MF7","684MF7","RN"
"684007","684MF7","RN"
EOF
```

On the whole, this is perhaps the better solution to use (and I shan't complain if you use `[0-9]` in place of `[[:digit:]]`).

Comment: Why is ^" repeated inside square brackets?

Comment: It isn't repeated (there's no `^^`); it is used to create a negated character class.  That is, `[^"]` matches any character except double quote (or newline), while `[^"[:digit:]"` matches any character except a double quote or a digit. This use is unrelated to `^` to mark the start of line, which appears outside of a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `.*` surrounding any other expressions tends to match more than expected. Try to write an expression that is more detailed with less large wildcard matches

I found this to work

```
> sed -n '/^".*[A-Z].*",".*",".*"/p' <(echo '"684MF7","684MF7","RN"')
> "684MF7","684MF7","RN"
> sed -n '/^".*[A-Z].*",".*",".*"/p' <(echo '"684117","684MF7","RN"')
>
```

It picks up all of the groups surrounded with "

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work for you?

```
 echo '"A84MF7","684MF7","3N"' | sed -n '/^"[^0-9,][^",]*"/p'
 "A84MF7","684MF7","3N"

 echo '"684MF7","684MF7","7N"' | sed -n '/^"[^0-9,][^",]*"/p'
 --Nothing--
```

Comment: Will `'/"[^0-9,][^",]*"/p'` pick up the first three numeric digits?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, `/"[^0-9,][^",]*"/p` reports the presence of a field such as `"RN"` that starts with a non-numeric..I thought that was the original requirement?

Comment: I'll go back and edit the OP. All the action takes place in the very first field. The alpha characters there prevent a cleaned-up .csv file from being loaded into an Informix table whose requirement is the first field be an integer.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, ok, added an anchor to pick up the first field